# shellscript if文でエラー

Tags: linux, shellscript

if文の書き方やユーザに入力させた文字を変数化する方法などを調べて実装しているのですが、
結果のようなエラーを吐いてしまいます。何がいけなかったのでしょうか？

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "apiモードはapi フルスタックモードはmvcと入力してください"
read MODE

if [ "$MODE" = "api"]; then
  echo "apiです"
elif [ "$MODE" = "mvc" ]; then
  echo "mvc"
else
  echo "無効な値が入力されました 最初からやり直してください"
  exit
fi
```

*結果*

```
/Users/user/script/mon: line 5: [: missing `]'
無効な値が入力されました 最初からやり直してください
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

エラーの出ている5行目で、閉じカッコ `]` の前に (半角の) スペースが無いのが原因だと思います。

**修正後:**

```
if [ "$MODE" = "api" ]; then
  echo "apiです"
elif [ "$MODE" = "mvc" ]; then
  echo "mvc"
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
こんな小さなミスだったとは・・・.